# shared library in static link, static library in dynamic link

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm writing a package MyPak that contains a library MyLib and an executable MyExe. Both rely on a third-party library Foobar. Depending on the system, Foobar is available either as shared or as static library.
I'm also free to chose whether to have MyLib shared or static.

If I chose to compile MyLib a shared library, it would make sense if Foobar is also available as shared. The link line for MyExe would then be something along the lines of

```
gcc -g myexe.c /path/to/mylib.so /path/to/foobar.so
```

What are the implications linking a static foobar here, i.e.,

```
gcc -g myexe.c /path/to/mylib.so /path/to/foobar.a
```

? Is this considered bad practice; does it have a negative impact on performance?

Likewise, if MyLib is static, does it hurt to do

```
gcc -g myexe.c /path/to/mylib.a /path/to/foobar.so
```

?
Are the consequences system-dependent?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to rephrase your question, because the vocabulary you are using makes it hard to understand. You don't "include" libraries into anything, you just link them. Also, what platform are you talking about ?